# Increase memory consumption by having kendo.all.min.js in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, memory-leaks, kendo-ui

I have an empty html file including **jquery.min.js and kendo.all.min.js** script tags. When I open this file in IE11 and refresh it constantly it doesn't indicate any increase in memory consumption(or memory leak) in **Developer Tools** but when I add this file to an **asp.net web application** and run it in visual studio, a **drastic  increase appeared** by each refreshing the page.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you substracted the memory used by Visual Studio itself?

Comment: It happens in client side (browser), only in IE. Google chrome and Firefox are fine

Comment: Pure guessing here but by default, VS does hook some debugging process to IE that allow you to debug the browser scripts directly in VS.  Try to install this application on a standalone IIS server and test it from another PC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did but result is the same